# pass URL of actual page in the input field of other page with jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a web site with page travel booking, on every page i want insert a button(book now), when click on this button i want go in another page(with contact form), this page with contact form i want add a input field (type hidden) ,and pass the link page of book travel  I just visited, so you understand where I'm getting the message.

example this is a form in the page mydomain.com/contact-form/

```
  <form>
      E-mail: <input type="email" name="usremail">
      <input type="hidden" id="getting-message" name="getting-message-url" value="Norway">
      <input id="buttonrequest" type="submit">
    </form>
```

and this is a button show on every book page :

```
<a href=""  id="reservation" class="button">Reservation</a>
```

how pass the URL of book page on the field "getting-message-url" when click on button ?

Comment: Consider `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` - [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). But if you are looking for a solution in jQuery / JS, why did you tag this as php?

Comment: i have a hard time understanding you!can you please be specific about what exactly do you want.

Comment: @psylogic   when click on button "reservation" pass the link of actual page in another page (in this another page show a contact form and in a imput field i want pass the url of a book page visited)

Comment: @Epodax    yes true , probable the best solution is only jquery/js

Comment: In regards to `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` the manual states *it cannot really be trusted*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `document.referrer`.The referrer property returns the URL of the page from where you navigated to the current page(the document that loaded the current document).

**Using Jquery**

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#getting-message').val(document.referrer);
});
</script>
<head>
<html>
<body>
    <form>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="usremail">
  <input type="hidden" id="getting-message" name="getting-message-url" value="Norway">
  <input id="buttonrequest" type="submit">
</form>
</body>
<html>
```

**Using Javascript**

```
document.getelementById('getting-message').value= document.referrer;
```

Comment: thanks for answer , can you send me a example with my code ?, thanks

Comment: i am not send never Down voters, probable other user , i tried your code but not work, but "getting-message-url" is not a id, not understand your code

Comment: i've changed it try now!

Comment: i have alredy tried the corect id , but not work. my original field is this "
<input type="text" name="text-744" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="hhhhh" aria-invalid="false">"

Comment: now it's work, the problem before is a jquery conflict

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your 'Reservation' button being a link, make it a form:

```
<?php
  $this_url = "http" . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
?>
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="from" value="<?php echo $this_url; ?>">
  <button type="submit">Reservation</button>
</form>
```

(change `contact.php` to whatever the location of your contact form is)

And then on your contact form:

```
<?php
  $from = isset($_POST['from']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['from']) : '';
?>
<input type="hidden" name="from" value="<?php echo $from; ?>">
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but have update the post, with only jquery/js, you have idea for make this without php ? thanks

Comment: @SURTLER77 Why have you removed the `php` tag from your question? This will work fine in PHP, anyway, and will support non-JavaScript users.

Comment: bacause this form is contact form 7 for wordpress, is very hard implement php for me on this plugin :(